# Is it possible to reference the servers object from another OpenAPI file?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I'm documenting a list of APIs using OpenAPI 3.0 and a separate YAML file for each API.

All APIs use the same target server, so currently I have the following in each API definition:

```yaml
...
servers:
  - url: www.abc.com   
    description: "Production Server"
```

But I don't want to repeat the `servers` in all API definitions. Instead, I would like to reference the `servers` from a single file, like so:

```yaml
# sample.yaml
...
servers:
  $ref: 'index.yaml#/servers'
```

But Swagger UI shows the "Could not render this component" error.

Is it possible to `$ref` the `servers` in OpenAPI 3.0 definitions?

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI 3.0 and 3.1 Specifications do not support `$ref` in `servers`.

Here's an existing feature request:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2338